# Updating and Deleteting SQLite row in ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

Hello I am very new to Android development and even Java for that matter, Im making an app that is supposed to connect to an SQLite database and be able to insert update, display and delete data. So far I am able to insert data and display it in a listview. From here my plan was to have two buttons in each item of the listview one to delete and one to update but I'm struggling getting the buttons to work any help would be appreciated thank you.

This activity is what takes the inputs and inserts a row into my table

```
package com.example.votesmart2;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import com.example.votesmart2.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Zip extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.zip);
            }


            @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.zip, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onSubmit(View view){

        System.out.println("button just pressed");

        FeedReaderDbHelper mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(getApplicationContext());

        System.out.println("database class instantized/database created");

        EditText first = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fname_input);
        String finalFirst = first.getText().toString();

        EditText last = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lname_input);
        String finalLast = last.getText().toString();

        EditText zip = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.zipcode_input);
        int finalZip = Integer.parseInt(zip.getText().toString());

        EditText age = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.age_input);
        int finalAge =Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());

        EditText sex = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sex_input);
        String finalSex = sex.getText().toString();
        System.out.println("gets all data from edit text");


        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        System.out.println("got writable database");

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.putNull(FeedEntry._ID);
        values.put(FeedEntry.col_first, finalFirst);
        values.put(FeedEntry.col_last, finalLast);
        values.put(FeedEntry.col_zip, finalZip);
        values.put(FeedEntry.col_age, finalAge);
        values.put(FeedEntry.col_sex, finalSex);



        long newRowId = db.insert(FeedEntry.table_name, null, values);



        Intent intent = new Intent(Zip.this, EditProfile.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

This is the activity that displays my data

```
package com.example.votesmart2;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.votesmart2.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class EditProfile extends ListActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("onCreate begins");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.editprofile);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        System.out.println("intent received");


        FeedReaderDbHelper feedReaderDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(this);
        System.out.println("istantiate db class");

        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        System.out.println("list view declared");
        ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, feedReaderDbHelper.getRecords());
        System.out.println("running of select query complete");
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        System.out.println("values sent to adapter for listview formatting");   

            }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.zip, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /*public void onDelete(View view){
        DeleteRecord deleteRecord = new DeleteRecord();
        deleteRecord.deleteRecord(null);
        Intent i = new Intent(EditProfile.this, EditProfile.class);  //your class
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
        }*/

    public void onUpdate(View view){

    }
}
```

This is my adapter

```
package com.example.votesmart2;


import com.example.votesmart2.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

    public ListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor){
        super(context, cursor);

    }
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.first_view).getTag();
        nameTextView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FeedEntry.col_first)));
        TextView lastTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.last_view);
        lastTextView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FeedEntry.col_last)));
        TextView zipTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.zip_view);
        zipTextView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FeedEntry.col_zip))); 
        TextView ageTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.age_view);
        ageTextView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FeedEntry.col_age)));
        TextView sexTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sex_view);
        sexTextView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FeedEntry.col_sex)));

        Button delete = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.delete);
        delete.setTag(nameTextView);


    }
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_list_item,  parent, false);


        return view;
    }

     public void onDelete()
       {
         //FeedReaderDbHelper dbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(context);
         //dbHelper.delete(nameTextView);
         FeedReaderDbHelper mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(null);//getApplicationContext()
         SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
         String selection = FeedEntry.col_first + " LIKE = ";
         String[] selectionArgs = { String.setTag()};
         db.delete(FeedEntry.table_name, selection, selectionArgs);
     }

}
```

and my database helper

```
package com.example.votesmart2;

import com.example.votesmart2.FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FeedReaderDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String text_type = " TEXT";
    private static final String int_type = " INTEGER";
    private static final String comma_sep = ", ";
    private static final String open_paren = " (";
    private static final String close_paren = ")";
    private static final String sql_create_entries = "CREATE TABLE " + FeedEntry.table_name + open_paren + 
            FeedEntry.col_id +  " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + 
            FeedEntry.col_first + text_type + comma_sep +
            FeedEntry.col_last + text_type + comma_sep +
            FeedEntry.col_zip + int_type + comma_sep +
            FeedEntry.col_age + int_type + comma_sep +
            FeedEntry.col_sex + text_type + close_paren;

    private static final String sql_delete_entries = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FeedEntry.table_name;

        //INCREMENT VERSION NUMBER IF CHANGE DATABASE SCHEMA
        public static final int database_version = 7;
        public static final String database_name = "VoteSmarter.db";

        public FeedReaderDbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, database_name, null, database_version);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL(sql_create_entries);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL(sql_delete_entries);
            onCreate(db);
        }

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        public Cursor getRecords(){
            String[] projection = { FeedEntry.col_id,
                    FeedEntry.col_first,
                    FeedEntry.col_last,
                    FeedEntry.col_zip,
                    FeedEntry.col_age, 
                    FeedEntry.col_sex};

            String sortOrder = FeedEntry.col_first + " DESC";

            Cursor c = db.query(FeedEntry.table_name, projection, null, null, null, null, sortOrder);
            return c; 
        }


        public void delete(TextView nameTextView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String selection = FeedEntry.col_first + " LIKE ?";
            String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(nameTextView)};
            db.delete(FeedEntry.table_name, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated i have been struggling with this for awhile now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to keep the view static? or how about if you just place a listener in the adapter and implement the function on the main activity, the when the delete button is touched the adapter will inform the listener and then the main activity can take care of the process of reloading the adapter.

In my case I have to different methods, the first one is to place the listener in the fragment and implement the activity in the main activity.

fragment:

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment{

public static final String TAG = ListFragment.class.getSimpleName();
private ListAdapter mAdapter;
private ListStoreAdapter sAdapter;
private ListView listView;
private Context mContext;
private View mView;
private OnItemSelectedListener listener;

public interface OnItemSelectedListener{
    public void onImageSelected(int p, View v, String r, String g, String f);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle args){
    super.onCreate(args);
    args = getArguments();

    ... create code goes here ...
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_view, container, false);
    mContext = getActivity();
    mView = view;
    setImage();
    return view;

}

public void setImage(){
    listView = (ListView)mView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listView.setAdapter(sAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) { 
            final View thumb = v.findViewById(R.id.itemViewList);
            String code;
            String flag;
            if(goodsCd != null){
                code = goodsCd[position];
            }else{
                code = "";
            }

            if(flags != null){
                flag = flags[position];
            }else{
                flag = "1";
            }
            listener.onImageSelected(position, thumb, codes[position], code, flag);
        } 
    });

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if (activity instanceof OnItemSelectedListener) {
        listener = (OnItemSelectedListener) activity;
    }else{
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()+" must implemenet HomeFragmentActivity.OnItemSelectedListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    // Guarantees that we never accidentally leak the Activity instance.
    listener = null;
}

}
```

Now as for the adapter is this one and also implements a delete function that calls a static void on the main activity that will refresh the whole fragment when the information changes.

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context mContext;
private boolean isCloud;

public ListAdapter(Context c, String[] d, File[] f, ArrayList<String> l, boolean i, String[] fn, String[] t, String[] cd){
    ... Initialise the variables here ...
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return files.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v;
    final ImageView imageView;
    TextView title;
    TextView date;
    ImageView checkMark, download;
    TableRow downloadBtn, deleteBtn, openBtn;

    if(convertView == null){
        v           = vi.inflate(R.layout.individual_list_cell, null);
        downloadBtn = (TableRow)v.findViewById(R.id.downloadBtn);
        deleteBtn   = (TableRow)v.findViewById(R.id.delBtn);
        openBtn     = (TableRow)v.findViewById(R.id.openBtn);
    }else{
        v            = (View)convertView;
        downloadBtn = (TableRow)v.findViewById(R.id.downloadBtn);
        deleteBtn   = (TableRow)v.findViewById(R.id.delBtn);
        openBtn     = (TableRow)v.findViewById(R.id.openBtn);
    }

    ... Some code goes here ...
            ... the delete button is as follow ...
    if(!isCloud){

        final String volString = files[position];
        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {HomeFragmentActivity.onDeletePressed(volString);}
        });

        downloadBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        deleteBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        openBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    return v;
}
```

}

And finally the main activity will implement the OnItemSelectedListener and will have the static void onDeletePressed

```
public class HomeFragmentActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity implements GridFragment.OnItemSelectedListener, ListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener,
                                                                OnCheckedChangeListener{
```

And the static void

```
public static void onDeletePressed(final String v){
    String msg = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.delete_warning);

            ... Prepare the code to delete the file in here ...

    AlertDialog alert = mBuilder.create();
    alert.setTitle(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.delete_title));
    alert.setMessage(String.format(msg, v));
    alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.ok_button),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            try{

                file.delete();
                                    //This will update the database
                localHelper.updateDownloadedMagazine(delVal, v);
                                    //Then update the array for the new fragment
                ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> localArray = localHelper.retrieveLocalMagazines();
                if(localArray != null){
                    volsArrayLocal = localArray.get(0);
                    datesArrayLocal = localArray.get(1);
                    codeArrayLocal  = localArray.get(2);
                    fileArrayLocal  = localArray.get(3);
                    titleArrayLocal = localArray.get(4);
                    coversLocal = new String[volsArrayLocal.size()];
                    for(int x=0; x< fileArrayLocal.size(); x++){
                        coversLocal[x] = volsArrayLocal.get(x)+Common.COVER_EXT;
                    }
                }
                                    //Replace the information of the fragment
                HomeFragmentActivity hf = new HomeFragmentActivity();
                //And call the function to replace the fragment
                                    hf.localOnClick();

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.cancel_button),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alert.show();

}
```

This method is working fine for me so far, I hope it can help you with your problem.

David